# XSD from XML with data validations

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a simple xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata>
    <Data Name="Title" Value="This is a new title." />
    <Data Name="Licensing_Window_Start" Value="2016-09-01" />
    <Data Name="Licensing_Window_End" Value="2016-09-14" />
    <Data Name="Preview_Period" Value="60" />
</Metadata>
```

I'm able to generate xsd online for the above xml like this,

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Metadata">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Data" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Value" use="required"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But what I'm trying to validate is, for `<Data>` tag, for the attribute `Name` the value `Title` is mandatory and need to define minlength and maxlength for the value of `Value`.

Is it possible to create the xsd with the type of validations I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it may depend on the XML Schema version you're using.

**Attribute Name the value Title is mandatory**

This can not be achieved with XSD 1.0, but with XSD 1.1 you can rely on assertions (`<xs:assert>`):

```
<xs:assert test="Data[@Name = 'Title']"/>
```

can be added in the `complexType` defining the content model of `<Metadata>`; an error will be raised if no `<Data>` with `Name="Title"` is found.

**Setting minlength/maxlength for `'Value'`**

You need to define and use a type with an `<xs:restriction>` (even if you could also embed the following snippet as a child of the `<xs:attribute name="Value">`:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="value-attr">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

and change your declaration of the attribute like so:

```
<xs:attribute type="value-attr" name="Value" use="required"/>
```

---

Finally you'll end up with the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Metadata">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Data" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="value-attr" name="Value" use="required"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="Data[@Name = 'Title']"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:simpleType name="value-attr">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

### XSD 1.1

See @potame's answer (+1).

### XSD 1.0

Not possible, but if you use less abstract element names,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata>
    <Title>This is a new title.</Title>
    <Licensing_Window_Start>2016-09-01</Licensing_Window_Start>
    <Licensing_Window_End>2016-09-14</Licensing_Window_End>
    <Preview_Period>60</Preview_Period>
</Metadata>
```

it will be trivial to represent that `Title` is mandatory (as well as your `minLength` and `maxLength` constraints).